# My Dynamic cart attributes - second attribute is showing the same value for every order

Tags: shopify

I have two dynamic dropdowns on my cart page for collecting cart attributes - the first is to select your state, and the second dropdown is a list of facilities in that state. Everything looks great on the front end. The first dropdown for states works and saves the information perfectly. The second dropdown, with the facilities looks good on the frontend, but saves the incorrect value each time - the second dropdown always saves the same value - 3108.

I load these using three files - my secondary dropdowns are now loaded in one html file, as it is too large to load in the cart-template.liquid file.

cart-template.liquid:

```
    <div> <p class="cart-attribute" id="PrisonDropdownCart" >
              <label><b>Please select</b> the state and name of the prison facility you are ordering for.</label><br>
                <label style="display:none;">State</label>
              <select required class="required states" id="state" name="attributes[state]">
                <option value="" disabled="" selected=""{% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Disabled" %} selected{% endif %}>Please Select a State</option>
                <option value="Alabama" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Alabama" %} selected{% endif %}>Alabama</option>
                <option value="Alaska" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Alaska" %} selected{% endif %}>Alaska</option>
                <option value="Arizona" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Arizona" %} selected{% endif %}>Arizona</option>
                <option value="Arkansas" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Arkansas" %} selected{% endif %}>Arkansas</option>
                <option value="California" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "California" %} selected{% endif %}>California</option>
                <option value="Colorado" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Colorado" %} selected{% endif %}>Colorado</option>
                <option value="Connecticut" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Connecticut" %} selected{% endif %}>Connecticut</option>
                <option value="Delaware" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Delaware" %} selected{% endif %}>Delaware</option>
                <option value="District of Columbia" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "District of Columbia" %} selected{% endif %}>District of Columbia</option>
                <option value="Florida" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Florida" %} selected{% endif %}>Florida</option>
                <option value="Georgia" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Georgia" %} selected{% endif %}>Georgia</option>
                <option value="Hawaii" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Hawaii" %} selected{% endif %}>Hawaii</option>
                <option value="Idaho" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Idaho" %} selected{% endif %}>Idaho</option>
                <option value="Illinois" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Illinois" %} selected{% endif %}>Illinois</option>
                <option value="Indiana" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Indiana" %} selected{% endif %}>Indiana</option>
                <option value="Iowa" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Iowa" %} selected{% endif %}>Iowa</option>
                <option value="Kansas" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Kansas" %} selected{% endif %}>Kansas</option>
                <option value="Kentucky" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Kentucky" %} selected{% endif %}>Kentucky</option>
                <option value="Louisiana" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Louisiana" %} selected{% endif %}>Louisiana</option>
                <option value="Maine" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Maine" %} selected{% endif %}>Maine</option>
                <option value="Maryland" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Maryland" %} selected{% endif %}>Maryland</option>
                <option value="Massachusetts" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Massachusetts" %} selected{% endif %}>Massachusetts</option>
                <option value="Michigan" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Michigan" %} selected{% endif %}>Michigan</option>
                <option value="Minnesota" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Minnesota" %} selected{% endif %}>Minnesota</option>
                <option value="Mississippi" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Mississippi" %} selected{% endif %}>Mississippi</option>
                <option value="Missouri" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Missouri" %} selected{% endif %}>Missouri</option>
                <option value="Montana" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Montana" %} selected{% endif %}>Montana</option>
                <option value="Nebraska" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Nebraska" %} selected{% endif %}>Nebraska</option>
                <option value="Nevada" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Nevada" %} selected{% endif %}>Nevada</option>
                <option value="New Hampshire" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "New Hampshire" %} selected{% endif %}>New Hampshire</option>
                <option value="New Jersey" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "New Jersey" %} selected{% endif %}>New Jersey</option>
                <option value="New Mexico" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "New Mexico" %} selected{% endif %}>New Mexico</option>
                <option value="New York" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "New York" %} selected{% endif %}>New York</option>
                <option value="North Carolina" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "North Carolina" %} selected{% endif %}>North Carolina</option>
                <option value="North Dakota" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "North Dakota" %} selected{% endif %}>North Dakota</option>
                <option value="Ohio" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Ohio" %} selected{% endif %}>Ohio</option>
                <option value="Oklahoma" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Oklahoma" %} selected{% endif %}>Oklahoma</option>
                <option value="Oregon" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Oregon" %} selected{% endif %}>Oregon</option>
                <option value="Pennsylvania" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Pennsylvania" %} selected{% endif %}>Pennsylvania</option>
                <option value="Puerto Rico" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Puerto Rico" %} selected{% endif %}>Puerto Rico</option>
                <option value="Rhode Island" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Rhode Island" %} selected{% endif %}>Rhode Island</option>
                <option value="South Carolina" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "South Carolina" %} selected{% endif %}>South Carolina</option>
                <option value="South Dakota" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "South Dakota" %} selected{% endif %}>South Dakota</option>
                <option value="Tennessee" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Tennessee" %} selected{% endif %}>Tennessee</option>
                <option value="Texas" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Texas" %} selected{% endif %}>Texas</option>
                <option value="Utah" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Utah" %} selected{% endif %}>Utah</option>
                <option value="Vermont" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Vermont" %} selected{% endif %}>Vermont</option>
                <option value="Virginia" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Virginia" %} selected{% endif %}>Virginia</option>
                <option value="Washington" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Washington" %} selected{% endif %}>Washington</option>
                <option value="West Virginia" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "West Virginia" %} selected{% endif %}>West Virginia</option>
                <option value="Wisconsin" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Wisconsin" %} selected{% endif %}>Wisconsin</option>
                <option value="Wyoming" {% if cart.attributes["state"] == "Wyoming" %} selected{% endif %}>Wyoming</option>
              </select>
              </p>

            <div id="PrisonDropdown">
            </div>   
            <br>
            </div>
 <script>
jQuery(function(){
$("#PrisonDropdown").load('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0060/7577/7135/t/2/assets/PrisonDropdown.html');
                  });
 </script>
```

theme.liquid:

```
{% if template == 'cart' %}
<script>
  jQuery(window).load(function(){ 
       $('.states').on('change', function(){
          var selected = $(this).val();
          $('.select-list').addClass('select-hidden');
          $('[id="' + selected + '"]').removeClass('select-hidden');

          })
        });

   </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. All the `if` statements from your HTML are not working and are loaded as-is because the liquid code is not rendered on requesting them this way, so just delete all of them.
2. The `3108` value is the **first** option from the **last** select box. As all your select boxes have the same name, no matter what do you display and select - the selected values from the last select box will always be sent on submitting the form. The quick solution for that would be moving the displayed select box to the bottom. You can do that by adding `.insertAfter(".select-list:last")` after removing the `select-hidden` class. So the whole line in your `theme.liquid` would look like the below:

   ```
   $('[id="' + selected + '"]').removeClass('select-hidden').insertAfter(".select-list:last");
   ```